# Insulation resistance or isolation resistance?

Tags: resistance, high-voltage, isolation, terminology, insulation

is there a difference between "isolation resistance" and "insulation resistance"? What is the correct term?

I have a definition:

"Electrical resistance with an often high ohm value that a non-conductor (e.g. the isolating coating of a wire) uses to counter an electrical current. Is measured to test whether the components and assemblies of electrical devices are designed such that leakage current does not exceed the specified standard values, preventing material damage and personal injury and guaranteeing operational safety."

I have many examples of sentences where either term is used, especially when it comes to high-voltage batteries.

1. The *isolation resistance* between the high-voltage busbar and electrical ground, with regard to the operating voltage, must be at least 100 Ω/V:
2. The internal resistance divided by the operating voltage of the high-voltage busbar yields the *isolation resistance* (in Ω/V).
3. Do not open the high-voltage battery unit while the *insulation resistance* remains unknown.

Thanks.

Comment: False friend from Germanic languages where insulate and isolate is the same word?

Comment: I am actually a translator from German to English, and many of the existing translations I am working with have "isolation". I am unsure if it is a translation mistake, a false friend as you say, or if there is actually a difference?? I am not an electrical engineer.

Comment: Here is an example of "isolation resistance" being use by Texas Instruments: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidudj6b/tidudj6b.pdf?ts=1679390693883

Comment: It is one thing doing translations between languages for "normal" things like stories or poems, but technical translations require a technical knowledge of how and why things work. I have had discussions with linguists who think they got the correct word, however they had the incorrect word due to not knowing the technical use or understanding the mechanism or process behind what was being discussed.

Comment: Solar Mike, yes, I agree. It's a different skill set than fiction. It is very hard, though, to find translators who know a lot about the field -- those specialists are usually working in the field!

Answer (score 1):

Isolation is often used when referring to galvanic isolation between circuits or parts of circuits. Sometimes provided by opto-couplers or opto-isolators, or isolation amplifiers.  The purpose often being safety, isolating a high-voltage part of a circuit from the low-voltage part that a user may interact with.

Insulation is often used specifically for a non-conducting material used to prevent shorting between conductors, or shock hazard.

However, the terms are closely related and in some cases could be used interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks John D. That is unfortunate because it makes my job difficult! In German it is always just "Isolationswiderstand" -- for both meanings. 

How confusing is it to the reader if the wrong term is used?

Comment: @Antonia I would be shocked (pun intended) if anyone were to misunderstand the meaning if the terms were interchanged.

Comment: @Antonia An example of where they are not interchangeable would be when talking about the coating or covering of a wire.  That's always insulation.  E.g. "This wire has Teflon insulation" or "You have to strip the insulation off of the end of that wire."  Isolation would sound wrong in those sentences.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: What would you use for the term described by this definition, something like "insulation monitor"? 

"Device that checks the presence and continued existence of the electrical insulation in a power supply. Monitors the insulation status of a grid within a power supply to check that the insulating resistance does not drop below the minimum value. As a rule, current to earth is measured. In the event of a fault, i.e. if the insulation fault current is exceeded, either a warning will be output or the output affected will be deactivated."

Comment: @Antonia That sounds OK to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation_monitoring_device

Comment: Thank you, John D. This has been very helpful indeed.